# Exception in Directory Entry

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I create new `DirectoryEntry` and I have exception in it

> (system.runtime.interopservices.comexception).

Previous `DirectoryEntry` is open ok (`directoryEntry`).

In `directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value` is correct value.

```
using (DirectoryEntry manager = new DirectoryEntry(Convert.ToString(directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value)))
{                
   contact.ManagersGuid = manager.NativeGuid;
}
```

Do you know where could be a problem? More opened directory entries in same moment?

Comment: what's in the exception details?

Comment: Message: not specified (not exactly this term, I have it localize to another language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is stored in `Properties["manager"].Value` ? My hunch is: that's not a complete, valid LDAP path......

If my hunch is correct, then you're not getting back a valid `DirectoryEntry` for the manager.

Try this code instead:

```
string manager = directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value.ToString();

// check what is stored in "manager" ! It needs to be a **full** LDAP path
// something like `LDAP://..........`

using (DirectoryEntry manager = new DirectoryEntry(manager))
{
   try
   {
      contact.ManagersGuid = manager.NativeGuid;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       // log and handle the exception, if something goes wrong....
   }
}
```

Comment: directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value must be retype to string. I don't know why, but in debug it is object. After change type to string it is correct LDAP path.